# How to find the integral of $\int_{o}^{u} x^{k}\frac{\alpha\theta^{\alpha}}{\left( x+\theta \right)^{\alpha+1}} dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I have tried to solve this by myself by letting $v=\frac{\theta}{x+θ} $... could you show me  an alternative way to get the integral of  $\int_{o}^{u} x^{k}\frac{\alpha\theta^{\alpha}}{\left( x+\theta \right)^{\alpha+1}} dx$?

Comment: It's the lower limit $o$ meant to be $0$?

Comment: Yup, it is zero... 0

Comment: Your approach gets the integral in terms of the [incomplete Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function), although $w=1-v$ would gel better with how it's defined.

Comment: Hello J.G., could you explain it more to me ?

Comment: Your substitution writes the integral as$$\int_{\frac{\theta}{u+\theta}}^1\alpha\theta^kv^{\alpha-k-1}(1-v)^kdv=\alpha\theta^k\left(\operatorname{B}(\alpha-k,\,k+1)-\operatorname{B}\left(\frac{\theta}{u+\theta};\,\alpha-k,\,k+1\right)\right),$$but my suggestion changes it to$$\int_0^{\frac{u}{u+\theta}}\alpha\theta^kw^k(1-w)^{\alpha-k-1}dw=\alpha\theta^k\operatorname{B}\left(\frac{u}{u+\theta};\,k+1,\,\alpha-k\right).$$

Comment: That’s very insightful. What did you let the variable u equals to?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The original integral is a function of $u$; when it's rewritten with these substitutions, this $u$-dependence is retained in one of the new limits.

Comment: I mean, I let $u =\frac{\theta}{x+\theta} $ in my approach... But if follow your suggestion, what should I let the $u$ equals to? :) Thanks for being patient to me.

Comment: You're already using $u$ for an integration limit. You can rename $v$ or $w$ if you like, but you can't call either of them $u$.

Answer (score 1):

We can use $x=v \theta$ substitution,
$$\therefore \mathrm{d}x=\theta \mathrm{d}v$$
$$\int _0^{u/\theta} (v\theta)^k \dfrac {\alpha \theta^{\alpha +1}}{\theta^{\alpha +1}(1+v)^{\alpha + 1}}\mathrm{d}v$$
$$=\int_0^{u/\theta} \alpha\theta^k \cdot\ \frac {v^k}{(1+v)^{\alpha+1}} \mathrm{d}v$$

$$=\alpha \theta^k \int_0^{u/\theta} \dfrac {v^k}{(1+v)^{\alpha +1}} \mathrm{d}v$$

Let $I_{(k,\alpha)} = \int \dfrac {v^k}{(1+v)^{\alpha +1}} \mathrm{d}v$

Now you need to simply apply *Integration by Parts* on $I_{k,\theta}$ by assuming $v^k$ as the first function and $(1+v)^{\alpha +1 }$ as the second function.

After one round of IBP we see,

$$I_{(k,\alpha)} = \dfrac {-\alpha v^k}{(1+v)^{\alpha}} + \alpha k(\int \dfrac {v^{k-1}}{(1+v)^{\alpha}} \mathrm{d}v)$$

Hence we get a relation,

$$I_{(k,\alpha)} = \dfrac {v^k}{(1+v)^{\alpha +1}}+I_{(k-1,\alpha -1)}$$

Using this equation recursively we can find $I$ for any value of $k$ and $\alpha$ .

Comment: Hey, thank you! However, I think in the 4th line, it should be $\alpha \theta ^{k-1}$... , right?

Comment: Also, second function in the IBP should be $\frac{1}{(1+v)^{\alpha+1}}$ right?

Comment: In fourth line I did not write $\alpha \theta^{k-1}$ since I ignored the constants as well as the limits and only wanted to find the indefinite integral. You of course need to apply the limits or multiply the constants at the end of the integration.

Comment: Second function in the IBP the power decreased by one since I integrated $\dfrac {1}{(1+v)^{\alpha +1}}$ so it becomes $\dfrac {1}{(1+v)^{\alpha}}$

Comment: Thank you ! Anyway, I have gone until $I_{k-2,\alpha -2}$ but seems like the recursion is unlimited... could you give me some insight on that? This is what I have got...

 
$ I = -\frac{\alpha ^k}{ (1+v)^\alpha} + \frac{\alpha k v^{k-1}}{(1-\alpha)(v+1)^{\alpha-1}} - \frac{\alpha k (k-1)}{1-\alpha}\int \frac{v^{k-2}}{(1+v)^{\alpha-1}} dv$ ...

Comment: The recursion depends on value of $k$ and $\alpha$, since power of both $k$ or $\alpha$ is decreasing by $1$, soon the integration is bound to come to a stop. Also ,the value of integration depends on whether $k \gt \alpha$ or $k \lt \alpha$ or $k=\alpha$

Comment: Does this mean that I will never get the integral of $I$ if I don’t have value of $k$ and $\alpha$ ?

Comment: Yes somewhat that is the case. Although there is another way to avoid all the IBP and find the integral directly, that again depends on value of $k$ and $\alpha$. As I said the indefinite integral changes depending upon if  $k \ge \alpha$ or  $k \le \alpha$.

Comment: If you want I can add that part in a edit.

Comment: Yeah, I would be greatly appreciated if you could add that part in an edit  need some insight ..